# Update props on child component with FlatList and Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I am using functional components and have implemented the following workflow using React Native. I have a parent component that retrieves the current location via a custom hook (using the useState and useEffect hooks) and has registered watchPositionAsync. The location is updated on the parent component. On the parent component, I use a FlatList with onPress that navigates to the next screen as a child component with some props. One of them is the "updated" location.
When I click on the list item, the current location is sent to the child component.

Now the location changes by the listener, but the updated location will only be sent to the parent component and not to the child component. How do I have to use hooks to register the updated location at the child?
The implementation is a bit like on http://5.9.10.113/67799305/how-to-add-clickable-flatlist-item-and-navigate-to-detail-component-in-react-nat
just with a dynamic url from the home component as a prop of Detail.

Comment: redux, react-redux may be the best solution for you. docs here https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `redux` or the context `api`. here is the simple solution has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68616653/is-it-possible-same-array-use-in-two-different-screen-for-react-navigation/68617252#68617252).

Comment: Redux looks a bit like to crack a nut with a sledgehammer. Is there an easier ways to get such results.

Comment: you can try the ContextAPI. Here I am sharing a link. https://blog.devgenius.io/react-native-state-management-with-context-api-61f63f5b099