# is it possible same array use in two different screen for react-navigation?

Tags: arrays, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist

In my app first screen is listing screen then second screen is detail screen.
when user tap on any item on listing screen open that item in detail screen.
detail screen also have listing but it fullscreen listing.
when user swipe down till end of data it get next page data.

I want when get next page data in detail screen it automatically update on listing screen.

> Is is possible use same array in both screen?
> If Yes then how or any reference?

Answer (score 0):

yes. it has two use cases. first and the best of of the use `redux` or `context API. you have to create your store and create an array that can be accessed on both screens.
here is a basic example of this.

https://github.com/AftabUfaq/ReduxCaller

the second one is that users can pass that array as params to the next screen. (this is good for beginners or if you have a small app).

Here is an example of this.

https://www.codegrepper.com/search.php?answer_removed=1&q=pass%20array%20as%20params%20in%20react%20navigation